# Why are we so sure about everything while commenting or answering?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, voting

In spirituality, we can't be assured like maths. Many times, there is a sense of **"statement"** in our comments & answers. We state them as of that's the ultimate truth for sure.

e.g. Recently, I came across a user who posted an answer in Quora which related "BrahmA --> Rajas" & "Rudra --> Tamas". I was asked to understand certain concept on this basis! I won't say, there is anything wrong with the user. But by making such 'statement', the user lost an opportunity to learn what could have been right. Even if the user was right, the opportunity of healthy discussion is lost.
Above was one of my many experiences. However, there are many places where I see lots of such "assured statements" made, which actually puzzles me that from where these users get such 'amazing confidence'!
<sub>To avoid irony, let me clarify that all my answers/comments should be taken with grain of salt even though they are backed up with scriptures. I have already put this disclaimer in my profile specific to this website.</sub>

Below are the possible bad side effects of it:

- **Information becomes Knowledge**: A bad thing for free-thinking. Information taken as it is, often turns out hazardous, because
  surrounding context keeps changing. Information becomes Knowledge, when
  taken in right context; "Knowledge" means, you "know" it, hence no more thought processing required!
- **Unwanted Debates**: Discussions are good until they are in good shape; Because no one wants to leave his/her stance, it becomes endless; One doesn't want to leave that stance, because of assurance as stated in Q
- **Misguidance**: When someone says something with full confidence, certain novice or soft hearted people will start believing it; When those novice will evolve in life, they would end up becoming dummies (good & bad)
- **Reduced voting**: For me, it's quite easy to (up)vote; Within short span, I have voted a lot. This doesn't mean I agree with all I have voted, but rather I pay respect to sincere effort. Now due to certain concepts have blocked our minds, if anyone speaks against it then we won't vote; There is an old question in this meta which covers lack of voting

Am I the only one who feels like this? Is there any scope of improvement here?

Comment: On a lighter note, it's highly recommended to watch [12 Angry Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Angry_Men_(1957_film)). It helped me to reduce the unwarranted assurance.

Comment: From this [video](https://youtu.be/1KrJvpD0nNM?t=1468), "My mommy is the best" => "My mommy is best, _for me_" :-)